# Determine the version of ANTLR being used by the ANTLR v4 grammar plugin for IntelliJ/JetBrains

Tags: intellij-idea, antlr, antlr4

I successfully installed the [*ANTLR v4 grammar plugin*](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358-antlr-v4-grammar-plugin) for [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), to utilize the [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) language-recognition framework.

How can I identify the version of ANTLR being used by the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ, go to `Preferences...`, then `Plugins` and select the ANTLR4 plugin. The version is mentioned somewhere:

[image]